# Update label text when radio is checked

Tags: c#, forms, radio-button, label

I have 3 different radio buttons and one label. How to update text on that label when radio is checked?

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Control item in groupBox1.Controls)
        {
            if(item.GetType() == typeof(RadioButton))
            {
                if (((RadioButton)item).Checked)
                {
                    label1.text = obj[item.TabIndex-1].name;
                }

            }

        }
    }
```

I wrote something like that but it is connected to button but i don't want it to work that way. I'd like to make event connected to all 3 radio buttons but i don't know how to do that.

Comment: What _exactly_ do you not know how to do? Attache an event handler to the radio buttons? What to write _in_ the event handler?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should look in to adding an event for each radio button.  Specifically, look at the [`CheckedChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.radiobutton.checkedchanged.aspx) event.

```
protected void ARadioButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is RadioButton)
    {
       RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton)sender;
       if (radioButton.Checked)
       {
           label.Text = ARadioButton.Text;
       }
}
```

Or as Oded mentioned, use the same event and take advantage of the `sender` parameter.  They will all point to the same event.

```
//somewhere in your form object, probably InitializeComponent()
ARadioButton1.CheckChanged += new EventHandler(ARadioButton_CheckedChanged);
ARadioButton2.CheckChanged += new EventHandler(ARadioButton_CheckedChanged);
ARadioButton3.CheckChanged += new EventHandler(ARadioButton_CheckedChanged);

protected void ARadioButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is RadioButton)
    {
        RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton)sender;
        if (radioButton.Checked)
        {
            label1.Text = "Clicked " + radioButton.Name;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can attach the _same_ event handler to the three buttons and **use** the `sender` parameter (casting to the correct type).

Comment: That was what i meant. I have one more question. Is there any way to make check which radio button was changed? I'd like to be able to change label's name to field's name from class. Each of those radio buttons is assigned to field in class. I'd like to use something like 'label1.text = obj[item.TabIndex-1].name;'

Comment: I came to the solution `Label.Text = obj[((RadioButton)sender).TabIndex - 1].name;` did the trick. I don't know if there is best way for do that but it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
btn1.Click += Button_Click;
btn2.Click += Button_Click;
btn3.Click += Button_Click;
```

however this is not a good approach but my answer is based on your question comment "I'd like to make event connected to all 3 radio buttons but i don't know how to do that."

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private void radioButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var element = sender as RadioButton;
        Debug.Assert(element != null, "element != null");
        if (element.Checked)
        {
            label1.Text = element.Name;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You first need to define the method that will handle the event. It can be exactly like your `Button_Click` method above, but you should change the name, for example to `radioButton_CheckedChanged`.

Next you need to connect this method to the event raised by the radio buttons when their selection status changes. This should be done in the form constructor, after the call to `InitializeComponent()`:

```
   radioButton1.CheckedChanged += new System.EventHandler (radioButton_CheckedChanged);
   radioButton2.CheckedChanged += new System.EventHandler (radioButton_CheckedChanged);
   radioButton3.CheckedChanged += new System.EventHandler (radioButton_CheckedChanged);
```

Replace `radioButton1`etc with the name of your radio controls.